# Regex of a RewriteRule isn't working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm actually using for the first time the RewriteRule command in a .htaccess, and I'm stuck...

What I'm trying to do is to make such redirection:

localhost/tchat/test_character.swf -> localhost/tchat/characters/test_character.swf

I'm using this current .htacces, as I don't know really where I was supposed to place it, I placed it in / and a copy in /tchat.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tchat/([^_/])_character\.swf$ /tchat/character/$1_character.swf [R=301]
```

But when I try to access the /tchat/test_character.swf I just get a 404...

I think the problem is in my regex but I just can't figure where inside the regex. I've already tried to add a `RewriteBase /` after the RewriteEngine On, and I also tried to add a / beetwen the ^ and tchat. But it doesn't worked.

So I'm really curious to know where the regex fail...

Thank's a lot!

Ps: Please excuse my English, It's not my native language :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked by changing the htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tchat
RewriteRule ^([^_/]+)_character\.swf$ /tchat/character/$1_character.swf [R=301]
```